# Run part of a command with sudo

Tags: command-line, permissions, sudo, htop, nice

I want to create a keybinding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> on my Ubuntu PC. It should open `htop`, but I want maximum priority for it. I use this command.

```
xterm -fullscreen -fa 'Monospace' -fs 13 -e htop
```

It works well, but when I add priority, it needs root permissions

```
$ nice -n -20 xterm -fullscreen -fa 'Monospace' -fs 13 -e htop
nice: cannot set niceness: Permission denied
```

When I use `sudo`, it works, but it runs the whole command as root. How can I run only `nice` with `sudo`? It would be ideal if it didn't ask for a password.

Comment: If you run nice with sudo, whatever command is run by nice will also be run as root, so you need to do `sudo nice ... sudo -u <some-user> xterm ...` Procedure for skipping passwords remains the same

Comment: avoiding the password seems like a bonus question here, looking at the title, your comment is the answer @muru (I think [How do I run 'sudo' command inside a script?](//askubuntu.com/a/425990) is more useful than the suggested target, if you don't want to answer the question)

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/271411). What do you hope to achieve by running `htop` at a negative priority? I can’t think of a reason that couldn’t be achieved better through other means.

Answer (score 1):

You can use nice on existing PID's with `renice`

So start the terminal as usual

`$ sudo renice -n -20 -p HTOP_PID`

If you are using different shells/windows for this, you can find the pid `ps -A | grep htop` there are numerous ways to extract PID from the output programmatically which would allow scripts to handle this.

Otherwise you could, as suggested in a comment, execute

`sudo nice -n -20 su USER htop` instead of straight `htop`